# org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at when converting xml to json

Tags: java, xml, json, rest

I have  a  xml file in some url location http://xy.com/test

I am trying to get the xml

```
  Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(" http://xy.com/test");
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);
        String textEntity=response.getEntity(String.class);
        //textEntity=textEntity.replace("\n", "");
        String xmlString= textEntity.toString();
        JSONObject xmlinJsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
```

I am getting below  exception I tried to remove \n character but problem persists.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 498551 [character 1 line 8394]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.XMLTokener.nextMeta(XMLTokener.java:181)
    at org.json.XML.parse(XML.java:176)
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:356)
    at com.intuit.fds.fdp.document.ws.resource.XMLtoJson.main(XMLtoJson.java:47)
```

Comment: Try printing out the soapmessageString once, check if all SOAP wrappers are stripped before you try to convert.

Comment: its not a soap message its plain xml

Comment: Can you include some of the XML as an example? By some I mean as much as necessary to show the breadth of the type of input.